# General error: 1364 Field 'description' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `tb_desc` (`month_year`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)

Tags: php, laravel, web

I'm using laravel website and got this message error while I'm trying to submit the data :
**"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'description' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `tb_desc` (`month_year`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2000 Juni, 2023-02-16 10:09:52, 2023-02-16 10:09:52))**"
here my code :

**DescriptionController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Description;

class DescriptionController extends Controller
{
    public function description_page(Request $request){
        $username = $request->session()->get('usernameAdmin');
        $logo = $this->getLogo();
        $description = Description::all();

        $data_count = $this->getDataCount();

        return view('admin.desc_award', compact('username', 'data_count', 'description', 'logo'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        if(Description::create($request->all())){
            return $this->response(0, 'Description Created Successfull');
        } else {
            return $this->response(1, 'Failed Created Description');
        }
    }

    public function update(Request $request){
        $description = Description::findOrFail($request->id);
        if($description->fill($request->all())->save()){
            return $this->response(0, 'Description Updated Successfull');
        } else {
            return $this->response(1, 'Failed Updated Description');
        }
    }

    public function destroy(Request $request){
        $description = Description::findOrFail($request->id);

        try {
          $description->delete();

          if( $description ){
            return $this->response(0, 'Success Delete Data');
          }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->response(1, 'Failed Delete Data');
        }
    }
}
```

**Description.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Description extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tb_desc';

    protected $fillable = [
      'id', 'month_year', 'description', 'description_en', 'description_ja'
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

}
```

is there something wrong with this code?

Comment: Your request doesn't have a "description" to store

Comment: but i already request all, can u be more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things you can do:

1. Add default value inside model using `attributes` as below:

   `protected $attributes = [ 'description' => 'a default value', ];`
2. Add into the `migration` default value as below:

   `$table->text('description')->default('some text');`
3. Make the `description` field nullable
4. You can also apply validation to throw an error when `description` is null.